# Request.GET not available in custom HTML Django Rest Framework renderer template

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this custom HTML renderer using Django Rest Framework:

```
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer

class CustomHTMLRenderer(TemplateHTMLRenderer):
    def
        renderer_context = renderer_context or {}
        view = renderer_context['view']
        request = renderer_context['request']
        response = renderer_context['response']

        if response.exception:
            template = self.get_exception_template(response)
        else:
            template_names = self.get_template_names(response, view)
            template = self.resolve_template(template_names)

        context = self.get_template_context({'content': data}, renderer_context)
        return template.render(context)
```

And this is my view for a search carried out on my Solr server:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination
import collections
from collections import OrderedDict
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
import scorched
from scorched.strings import DismaxString

from bassculture.renderers.custom_html_renderer import CustomHTMLRenderer

class SearchResultsPagination(LimitOffsetPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        
        self.solr_response = data['solr_response']
        self.offset = self.solr_response.result.start
        self.limit = len(data['records'])
        self.count = self.solr_response.result.numFound
        self.request = data['request']

        resp = Response(OrderedDict({
            'count': self.count,
            'next': self.get_next_link(),
            'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
            'results': data['records'],
            'facets': self.solr_response.facet_counts.facet_fields,
            'params': self.solr_response.params,
            'highlighting': self.solr_response.highlighting,
            'limit': self.limit,

        }))

        return resp


class SearchViewHTMLRenderer(CustomHTMLRenderer):
    template_name = "search/search.html"

class SearchView(GenericAPIView):
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer, SearchViewHTMLRenderer]
    pagination_class = SearchResultsPagination

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        querydict = request.GET
        offset = querydict.get('offset', 0)

        fcq = {}
        for f in settings.SEARCH_FACETS:
            if querydict.get(f, None):
                fcq[f] = querydict.get(f)

        fq = {}
        if querydict.get('fq'):
            fq = querydict.get('fq')
        else:
            fq = '*'

        si = scorched.SolrInterface(settings.SOLR_SERVER)
        response = si.query(DismaxString(querydict.get('q'))).filter(**fcq).filter(fq).highlight('*', fragsize=10).paginate(start=int(offset), rows=api_settings.PAGE_SIZE).facet_by(fields=settings.SEARCH_FACETS, mincount=1).execute()

        for d in response:
            d['highlighted_string'] = response.highlighting[d['id']]
        results_list = response

        records = []
        for result in response:
            type = result['type']
            pk = result['id'].split('_')[1]
            result['url'] = request.build_absolute_uri(os.path.join('/fiddle/', type, pk))
            records.append(result)

        d = {
            'records': records,
            'solr_response': response,
            'request': request,
        }
        resp = self.get_paginated_response(d)

        return resp
```

The JSON of the results is coming through. In fact, if I change the renderer_classes to

```
renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
```

the browser shows the raw JSON. So, I suppose, there's an issue with my HTML renderer. What could it be? The HTML renderer works just fine in the other pages of my website (where I do not have to deal with JSON data).

Django==3.1.4
djangorestframework==3.12.2

**UPDATE**

I've discovered that the issue is that I am not able to access my request parameters from my template. I had a

```
{% if request.GET.q %}
Results....
{% endif %}
```

which was nullifying the results page.

How can I access my requests parameters? I do have `'django.template.context_processors.request'` in my settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add `request=request` in my return `template.render` call:

```
return template.render(context, request=request)
```